# How to find a specific error message?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding, searching

Is there a way to find an existing error message in the `` System` `` context, that is used for a certain case? I want to include a message in a custom function that compares all the arguments of the function, and checks if they have the same length. I'm pretty sure that there is one such, but I can't seem to find it. And I don't want to insert new symbols or messages to the namespace if I can use existing ones. Now I am looking for a method that is general; i.e., it can be applied to other cases, not just this one with argument lengths.

For example I am looking for a message that works like this:

```
General::badlen = "The length of arguments `1`, `2`, `3` must be the same.";

myFun[x_List, y_List, z_List] /; 
  If[Length@x == Length@y == Length@z, True,
     Message[myFun::badlen, x, y, z]; False] := x*y*z;
```

Comment: The nearest message that I am aware of is `General::bldim`... anyway, you might want to look for appropriate messages that you can use within `Messages.m`, which is in the directory `$InstallationDirectory <> "/SystemFiles/Kernel/TextResources/English"`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. It could be a perfect answer...

Comment: I don't think it's a completely optimal message, tho. You'll of course need to inscribe additional code to determine which two of the three arguments given have the incompatibility... also, there might be a better error message within `Messages.m`; I just got lazy after five minutes.

Comment: @J.M. Well, my Q is not about this specific error message (it could have been any other task), but the way how to access/query/find built-in error messages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a tiny utility function you might use if you're trying to look for a message that contains a known string:

```
searchMessages[str_String, opts___] := 
      Sort[Select[Flatten[Map[ToExpression[#, InputForm, Defer] :>
                              Evaluate[ToExpression[#]] &,
           StringCases[FindList[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles",
                                              "Kernel", "TextResources", "English",
                                              "Messages.m"}], str, opts,
                                IgnoreCase -> True],
                       RegularExpression["([\\w$]|`)+::(\\w)+"]], {2}]],
                  With[{s = Last[#]},
                       StringQ[s] && ! StringFreeQ[s, str, IgnoreCase -> True]] &]]
```

For example,

```
searchMessages["determinant"]
   {TransferFunctionModel::method :> 
    "Value of option Method -> `1` is not Automatic, \"DeterminantExpansion\",
     \"ResolventIdentities\", \"Inverse\", or Generic."}
```

The function tries to search for apropos messages within the `Messages.m` file within the system files. It won't always find an appropriate message, since there are messages like `General::offline` that aren't within `Messages.m` (though `grep` tells me that that particular message is in `$InstallationDirectory <> "SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Kernel/Services.m"`, so you know what to modify). Still, it's a start...

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem: as I said, I'm lazy, so I wrote a routine to do the searching for me...

Comment: That's not the meaning of lazy.  Lazy is doing this by hand repeatedly until someone else wrote `searchMessages` for me... :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ... or for me. Now I feel the shame... :)

Answer (score 6):

We can scan the messages that have been loaded into the current session like this:

```
messages[pattern_, context_:"*"] :=
  Cases[
    Quiet[ToExpression[#, InputForm, Messages]& /@ Names[context~~"*"], General::readp]
  , (_[n_] :> m_String) /; !StringFreeQ[m, pattern, IgnoreCase -> True] :> HoldForm@n :> m
  , {2}
  ]

messages["arguments", "System`"]
(*
{General::bldim:>The arguments `1` and `2` in `3` do not have compatible dimensions.}
*)

messages["longer"]
(*
{General::partd:>Part specification `1` is longer than depth of object.,
 Part::partd:>Part specification `1` is longer than depth of object.}
*)
```

The emphasis here is on *loaded* messages.  This method will not find any messages in packages that have not yet been loaded.  Also beware that some packages load symbols (and their messages) lazily, on demand.