# Unsetting messages

Tags: usage-messages

The following code suggests that Mathematica stores the messages in cache:

```
(*1*)Remove[VariationalD]
(*2*)Messages[VariationalD]
(*3*)Message[VariationalD::args, OPS]
(*4*)Messages[VariationalD]
```

The output of the second line is `{}` as expected for a symbol that has just been removed. The output of the third line however is not the expected "-- Message text not found --". Instead, Mathematica seems to have pulled that message from some cache.

In any case, **how can I reset the message cache (without resetting the whole installation)?**

---

**Update**

I apologize because my previous example did not really work. In any case, the following is a better example. This code was executed on a freshly launched kernel.

```
before = Messages[General]; Message[General::dummies, OPS];
after = Messages[General]; Complement[after, before]
```

[image]

The message `General::dummies` was not part of the original list of messages attached to `General`. Following the documentation, the next place to check would be `$NewMessage`, but `Messages[$NewMessage]` is empty. So, where did `General::dummies` come from?

Comment: You could do `Messages[VariationalID] =.` ... BTW I can't reproduce the problem you mention.

Comment: @Szabolcs: `Messages[VariationalID] =.` did not work. The message might need to be loaded into the cache by loading the package. Once in the cache, it seems to stay there.

Comment: I had a typo which you copied and pasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mathematica* loads many of its built-in messages from the file

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","Kernel","TextResources","English","Messages.m"}]
```

As I understand it is the "message cache" you seek. The search in this file can be controlled through the `$NewMessage` variable. By default its value is `Automatic`:

```
ClearAttributes[$NewMessage, {Protected, ReadProtected}]

Definition@$NewMessage
```

> $NewMessage = Automatic

By unsetting it you can disable search in the above-mentioned file as well as in other files in that folder:

```
$NewMessage =.
```

Also, you can be interested in this discussion: "[How to find a specific error message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14792/280)"

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug.

There is `General::args` and `VariationalD::args`.  The former message is a general one that can be issued for *any symbol*:

```
Message[boo::args, "something"]

boo::args: something called with invalid parameters.
```

This can be overridden by setting a message for that particular symbol:

```
In[5]:= boo::args = "custom message"

In[6]:= Message[boo::args]

During evaluation of In[6]:= boo::args: custom message
```

You can simply remove all messages associated with a symbol using

```
Messages[boo] =.
```

Now try again:

```
Message[boo::args, "something"]

boo::args: something called with invalid parameters.
```

This works the same way for `VariationalD`.

---

Quoting from the `Message` documentation,

> Given a message specified as `symbol::tag`, `Message` first searches for
>   messages `symbol::tag::Subscript[lang, i]` for each of the languages in
>   the list `$Language`. If it finds none of these, it then searches for
>   the actual message `symbol::tag`. If it does not find this, it then
>   performs the same search procedure for `General::tag`. If it still finds
>   no message, it applies any value given for the global variable
>   `$NewMessage` to symbol and `"tag"`.

Comment: In the documentation of `$NewMessage`, I found "A typical value for $NewMessage might be `Function[ToExpression[FindList[files,ToString[MessageName[#1,#2]]]]]`." This tells me that Mathematica can be set up to look into your packages to find messages.