# how to obtain all Messages for Mathematica build-in functions?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding, system-variables

Help says `Messages[symbol]` gives all the messages assigned to a particular symbol. These are called message identifiers per help:

> Message names always consist of a function name and message identifier
>   separated by a double colon (::).

I wanted to find all possible error/warning message identifiers that say the function `DSolve` can throw. Such as `DSolve::dvlen` and so on without having to search for them one by one in different help pages.  It will also be nice to know which is an error message vs. a warning message if possible.

But `Messages[DSolve]` returns empty, because help says `Typically, for system commands, messages are only loaded when they are required:`

Is there a way, may be using `MathematicalFunctionData` ? or in other ways to obtain complete list of such messages?

V 12.1 on windows.

Reference

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Messages.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageName.html

Comment: There's also the thing that some messages are really attached to `General` so they cannot be listed using `Messages[symbol]`.

Comment: When I wrote up [`searchMessages[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14799), I used `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", "TextResources", "English", "Messages.m"}]` as the primary source. Of course, not all the messages used by *Mathematica* are in there, for some reason. And yes, Szabolcs is correct that any message associated with `General` can be generically associated with other functions: the message you get when evaluating `1/0` is attached to `Power`, but is actually from `General::infy`.

Comment: My wish is that such a list of messages is placed somewhere on top of a documentation page for a symbol. How can you handle exceptions without knowing what's going to be thrown at you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ListMessages[sym_Symbol] := Module[{},
  FileNameJoin[{System`Private`$MessagesDir, $Language,"Messages.m"}] // Get // Once; 
    Block[{MessageName}, Grid[Messages[sym] /. RuleDelayed -> List /. 
      MessageName[a_, b_] :> (ToString[a] <> "::" <> ToString[b]) /. 
      HoldPattern -> Identity, Alignment -> {Left}]]
  ]
```

And then

```
ListMessages[DSolve]
```

returns

[image]