# Is there a comprehensive list of most common or most important native Message-s (w/tags) for errors and Failed?

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, built-in-symbols, message-coding, general-utilities

Yes I understand how to use `Messages[symbol]` but that doesn't help much. I have no idea which important ones I may have missed in my search or even how many exist. Are there a mere 100 or so or tens of thousands? I am also aware of doing `Messages[General]` which gives about 4 or 5 dozen. In most cases this should suffice however I would rather not repeat code native to the system by creating new `Message`-s.

Since I have your attention how does one determine which *messages* go with `Message` (for *errors*) and which go with `Failed` and `Failure`?

**Error or Failed?**
I tend to use the following rules of thumb:

- **Errors**: tend to be bad argument inputs for example when a string is expected but string is defined with single quotes instead of
  double or expecting a list of text files but inadvertently sending a list of Excel files.
- **Failed**: Unable to retrieve anything from anywhere (files, data, other objects) or unable to perform a remote process anywhere
  in the world you may be connected to including your own darn computer
  drive.

Does this sound correct to you? How would you change it?

To sum it up I would like to see a list of most common `Message`-s for both errors and `Failure` (or `Failed`) for use as a reference.

Thank you I hope I'm not asking for too much. :)

Comment: What do you need them for?

Comment: @MarcoB great question. right now I am only coding basic system personalization such as customizing `$Path`, automating the creation of packages, and lots and lots of custom interface construction, and automating many other general system tasks, but very little math and science although in a few months I will be flooded with it. so I guess I answered my own question.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14792/how-to-find-a-specific-error-message -- There are over 8000 of them in `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", "TextResources", "English", "Messages.m"}]`.  I don't know if the list is comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `System` context

```
systemNames = Names["System`*"];

Length@systemNames

(* 7091 *)

messages = Flatten[
    Messages /@ Cases[ToExpression /@ systemNames, _Symbol]] // 
   Quiet;

Length@messages

(* 4400 *)
```

Comment: Messages are often dynamically loaded when particular errors occur.  Until they are loaded, they do not show up in `Messages[symbol]`.

Comment: @BobHanlon wow that's well over 11000 just for the main context. that's just crazy!